# iOS 16 Isolated Subject Location

Tags: ios, photos, video, storage, copy-paste

Where are the isolated objects saved on iOS 16?
Is it the clipboard or some other location?
Does it retain the original image's metadata?
Is the copy-entire-image function now not accessible through a long-press of an image?

Answer (score 2):

They are not saved afaik and only exist on the clipboard. You can use [multitasking to bring up another app](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/patterns/multitasking/) to drag and drop the image.

You can also tap on the photo once you’ve made the layer and copy / share. This is shown with a video in the tips app under what’s new ion iOS 16 under “Remove the background of a photo”

- https://www.macrumors.com/how-to/isolate-copy-share-subjects-photos/

If you just wish to save them, notes app is a great spot to park them.

Answer (score 0):

Long press in the subject, choose share, choose save image from the menu below or any other sharing options, if you choose save it will be on your photos.

To see if it preserves metadata, choose info option on the new image, this may vary according to your privacy photos settings.